# Send data using GCM from server to mobile app

Tags: android

Can we send data (JSON form) using google cloud messaging service? I want to send data from server to mobile application when new data arrived from sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `data` field. Data messages can have a 4KB maximum payload.

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
 }
```

Font: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages